# Download any file after submitting a form

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-contact-form-7, contact

I wanted to know if you know of a plugin, or a method so that when the user fills in and sends it to the form, they automatically download a file. I currently use the plugin contact form 7

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "actions". More info: http://hookr.io/actions/wpcf7_mail_sent/

Put this code in your functions.php:

```
function action_wpcf7_mail_sent( $contact_form ) { 
    // here your file redirect
    header("Location: http://yourfileurl.com"); 
}; 

add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'action_wpcf7_mail_sent', 10, 1 );
```

let me you if it is working i cannot test right now.

Comment: It does not work, I currently have a multisite wordpress environment, will it be for that?

Comment: @Horiuko if it doesn't do what you expected, what does it do instead? Be careful, saying it doesn't work might mean that when you clicked the button, your computer turned into a drone and flew away, or that instead of downloading a file, an amazon delivery person arrived at the door with the file on a USB drive, or that it downloaded the wrong file, or that your browser crashed etc etc

Comment: It was not necessary so much sarcasm, I do not have your knowledge, my mistake ... but I feel that my answer is valid. It did not work, because the action of the hook is not calling the download file. That's why I say, if it is feasible that this happens because I have the wordpress environment as a multisite. But in the same way, thank you for your help.

Comment: OK, probably what i wrote is deprecated. Try this: [https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-extras/](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-extras/)

image:
[example image](http://cf7skins.com/wp-content/uploads/contact-form-7-controls-redirect.png)